# Need to decode CLUSTD column SAP Hana

Tags: binary, decode, saprfc, pyrfc, read-text

i am looking to decode the CLUSTD column of SAP, which is in encoded form as binary. I want to decode it outside SAP, I know READ_TEXT helps decode it but it is in SAP environment.

My CLUSTD is in SNowflake after migration and I want to decode it using may Python Library(PyRFC). Is the thing possible? What solutions we can have.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: CLUSTD is compressed using SAP-proprietary compression algorithm. `READ_TEXT` can be called externally via RFC protocol, using `RFC_READ_TEXT` function module.

Comment: try to find an SAP connector for Snowflake

Comment: Thanks @SandraRossi, where we can find RFC_READ_TEXT? Is Python module fine to use?

Comment: Use PyRFC to call the SAP function `RFC_READ_TEXT`. You can't just decode `CLUSTD` after it has been extracted, unless you are an experienced ABAP developer (+ SAP license needed to develop in the ABAP system).

Comment: Thanks - So just to make sure, I understand, we can decode the CLUSTD after it has been extracted, but it has to be done with a function module RFC_READ_TEXT